# Invalid timestamp in jenkins

Tags: timezone, timestamp, jenkins

Everywhere absolute timestamps are displayed, they are shifted an hour back.
E.g. subversion polling log, build history.

It seems that DST is applied, however it is cancelled in Russia.

Timezone on client machine is okay. Timezone on jenkins server is okay. `date` on server shows appropriate time.

Jenkins-Manage Jenkins-System info-system properties shows correct user.timezone.

Relative timestamps are calculated well (something like `31 min ago`) as it should.

How can i correct this incorrect behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
The reason was recent timezone change in Russia (DST was cancelled). And though it was half a year ago, my java jre didn't know about it. And timezone is not autoupdated at all.

I took utility from https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/dst/jtzu.html and replaced relevant javazi files in my java installation. Jenkins server was headless, so I didn't use the utility itself. Just replaced some files in /usr/lib/jvm//jre/lib/zi with files from archive.

After restarting Jenkins timestamps became good.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can also be triggered by this strange Ubuntu / Debian bug in the Java tzdata files:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/+bug/1052613

Reinstalling the tzdata-java package will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug. Here's [a similar bug](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-26959) in a Java application. As a workaround, start Jenkins with a time zone that is an hour away.